# Node issues: NPM is giving me errors of all kinds

Tags: node.js, npm

This is the error I get everytime:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "-g"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\uche\npm-debug.log
```

[image]

Comment: I am also receiving the same output, but on 10.0.10586. I'm on brand new Surface Book (literally a day out of the box or so) and a non-proxy connection.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mostly due to network errors.

Make sure your internet connection is up and there isn't any restriction due to firewall, vpn , etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by running this command

```
npm cache clean
```